# Combining abstract classes somehow?

Tags: kotlin

Let's say we have an abstract class A with feature A, we also need an abstract class B with feature B that extends A. Later on, we make an abstract class C with feature C that extends A.

Is it possible somehow to have an abstract class that has features B and C, without reimplementing (rewriting code) one of them?

```
abstract class A { fun featureA() { /* implementation */ }  }

abstract class B: A() { fun featureB() { /* implementation */ }  }

abstract class C: A() { fun featureC() { /* implementation */ }  }

abstract class D: C() { fun featureB() { /* how can the implementation be avoided? */ }  }
```

I don't mind if there aren't abstract classes per se, but it's required to have the implementation of corresponding feature.

Comment: If you have access to the code of all these superclasses, you could implement these features in A as protected functions, and then selectively override them to make them public in the subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use interfaces? Since you're really trying to compose a class from types `B` and `C`, that's a better fit than trying to inherit from both. You can [inherit from other interfaces](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html#interfaces-inheritance) and use their implementations:

```
interface A {
    fun beA() { print("A!") }
}

interface B : A {
    fun beB() { print("B!") }
}

interface C : A {
    fun beC() { print("C!") }
}

class D : B, C {
    fun beD() { print("D!") }
}

fun main() {
    with(D()) {
        beB()
        beC()
        beD()
        beA()
    }
}

>> B!C!D!A!
```

Interfaces can have properties, but not with backing fields, so they have to be abstract - you can't assign a default value in the interface. So that's a limitation you might run into vs actual abstract classes. But you can create properties with getter functions:

```
interface A {
    val luckyNumber = 777 // nope
    val luckyNumber get() = 777 // yep
}
```